# Building a library that uses an optional library

Tags: android, libraries

I have an Android library that helps implement and add various GUI components the Android navigation drawer.

Currently the library will only support the full APIs from the supported API, i.e. from Honeycomb onwards.

I want to change the library so it can also work with AppCompat, that shouldn't be a problem as it is likely to always to be installed and available.

The problem I have, a couple of users who use the library have requested that my library can support the use of the ActionBarSherlock library as well.

I don't want to do to separate navigation drawer management libraryies, and app compat and then a separate library for ActionBarSherlock so what I am wondering is if there is a way I can make a class that uses ActionBarSherlock libraries but will only attempt to compile/use the classes(s) if ActionBarSherlock is available.

Therefore the user can use my one library and be able to use all 3 different types of navigation drawer without needing multiple different libraries to support them.

My library is used within Android Studio not Eclipse

Comment: Depending on how your library is setup you can add an enum type to your constructors that determines which form of the library they need to use and leave it up to users to understand (Type.ACTION_BAR_SHERLOCK) means that they need ActionBarSherlock. Crap hacked together way of doing it but it is a way :P

Comment: Not sure how that would work. If my library is using ABS then my library has to reference ABS. I can't include ABS library built into mine I wouldn't have thought, so the developer using my library would have to make sure ABS is referenced. If the developer isn't using ABS, then my library won't be able to include ABS library, therefore my library won't compile

Comment: Ohhhh I gotcha, I didn't recognize the dilemma but I get it now. I think you can actually include ActionBarSherlock in your library (if it's jar is placed in your lib's lib folder it should be built with it... I think).

Comment: Ah OK, I was trying to avoid that, one I wasn't sure if there was license issue with ABS doing that, and 2 I have to upgrade my library everytime they release a new version of their library.

Comment: I gotcha, and understand that issue as well. You may be better off making a separate library to support ABS (I know you said you didn't want to though). I will stop with suggestions as someone else will likely have a better idea, but to answer your question; short answer - yes you can break up compiled code using static final modifiers, long answer - no you can't make dynamic variable compile-time decisions as to what code get's compiled when.